# Understanding numpy "void" dtype and generic arrays

Tags: python, arrays, generics, numpy

I'm trying to create a numpy array containing 2 element tuples, where the first one could be anything and the second one is an integer. Reading numpy docs I discover the numpy.void type as a kind of generic type. If I define my new type as:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: dt = np.dtype([('anything', 'V', 1), ('counter', 'i4', 1)])
```

I can do:

```
In [3]: np.array([("hi", 1), ("bye", 1)], dtype=dt)
Out[3]: 
array([(<read-write buffer ptr 0x12f9bb0, size 1 at 0x7f03d020f870>, 1),
   (<read-write buffer ptr 0x12f9bb5, size 1 at 0x7f03d020f830>, 1)], 
  dtype=[('anything', 'V1'), ('counter', '<i4')])
```

But I cannot do:

```
In [4]: np.array([(1, 1), (2, 1)], dtype=dt)
------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-637fcc25185b> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array([(1, 1), (2, 1)], dtype=dt)

TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

Is there a way of having generic tuples using numpy dtypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dtype `O` (object) may be more general than `V`.  The array will then have space at the point for a pointer - which can point to any kind of Python object, whether it's a string, number, list, tuple, or a custom class.

```
In [85]: dt=np.dtype([('anything', 'O'), ('counter','i4')])

In [86]: np.array([("hi",1), ("bye",1), ((1,1),2), (3,4)],dtype=dt)
Out[86]: 
array([('hi', 1), ('bye', 1), ((1, 1), 2), (3, 4)], 
      dtype=[('anything', 'O'), ('counter', '<i4')])
```

I think that the `V1` in your specification is a byte devoid of meaning, what your first case describes as `<read-write buffer ptr 0x12f9bb0, size 1 at 0x7f03d020f870>`.

---

Here's a way in which a large enough `void` could function as serialization buffer

```
In [119]: dt1=np.dtype([('anything', 'V',10), ('counter','i4')])
In [120]: A1=np.zeros(5,dt1)

In [121]: A1['anything'][0]=b'anything'
In [122]: A1['anything'][1]=b'0123456789'


In [123]: A1['anything'][2]=pickle.dumps((1,2)) 
In [124]: pickle.loads(A1['anything'][2])
Out[124]: (1, 2)
```

I defined a field as a `V10` buffer.   I can assign to individual elements of this field any byte string up to that length, including the output of a `pickle.dumps`.

```
In [128]: pickle.dumps((1,2))
Out[128]: b'\x80\x03K\x01K\x02\x86q\x00.'
```

Trying to pickle `(1,2,3)` doesn't work - I can make the assignment, but the loads fails because the whole buffer did not fit.

```
In [156]: A1
Out[156]: 
array([([97, 110, 121, 116, 104, 105, 110, 103, 0, 0], 0),
       ([48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57], 0),
       ([-128, 3, 75, 1, 75, 2, -122, 113, 0, 46], 0),
       ([-128, 3, 71, 64, 40, -103, -103, -103, -103, -103], 0),
       ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 0)], 
      dtype=[('anything', 'V10'), ('counter', '<i4')])
```

So we'd have to dig around a bit to figure out how to return the byte strings that I initially defined.  Numbers will also have to serialized in one way or other.  We can always fall back on `pickle` for everything.  `JSON` is another serializing option.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason for using numpy and no other generic python structure is because of a requirement in terms of a serialization library that I need to use. This serialization process imposes the restriction that every object must be mapped into a numpy.dtype type. Dtype O (object) is a derived type and is not acepted. I assume the case might be that is no possible to map anything into a numpy.void type. I'll wait a little bit to see if anyone comes with a solution before accepting yours as the good answer.

Comment: I've added an example with a multibyte void, and the use of `pickle` to serialize.